# Contiguous page ref in backref

Tags: back-referencing

Is there a way to make the `backref` package print "*pages 1-4*" for contiguous pages, instead of "*pages 1, 2, 3, and 4*"?

I think I must begin with:

```
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
    \ifcase #1 %
        No citation.%
    \or
        Cited on page #2.%
    \else
        Cited #1 times on pages #2.%
    \fi}%
```

I found this [Re: Page numbers to refs: Adding the word 'page' to pagebackref](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3670#p14351), but it is not a solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Cleverref might solve your problem

Comment: What is the purpose of backref without showing the specific page numbering? For me it doesn't make any sense. Moreover, how many times the same reference is called in sequential pages? Once? Twice? Really, I think it is not interesting to do what you asked. Anyway, I wish I could help.